# call javascript based on country

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I am trying to call on some javascript code based on the users country. I found a service, but it doesn't work for me. It won't load my javascript. It won't even load an alert message, when I change the if statement to if(country == "US"). This is what I have.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country != "US") {
var iLoader={
    init:function(){
        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
        var scrNode = document.createElement('script');
        scrNode.type = 'text/javascript';
        scrNode.id = 'iLoader';
        scrNode.src = 'https://scriptIWantToRun.js';
        headID.appendChild(scrNode);    
    }
}
}
</script>
iLoader.init();
```

This is the javascript how I had it prior and it worked. However I found that USA & Canada visitors don't need this info, only international users. So I would like to disable it for USA and CAN users. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
var iLoader={
    init:function(){
        var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
        var scrNode = document.createElement('script');
        scrNode.type = 'text/javascript';
        scrNode.id = 'iLoader';
        scrNode.src = 'https://scriptIWantToRun.js';
        headID.appendChild(scrNode);    
    }
}
iLoader.init();
```

I simplified it and got it to work when using the below code. However, I need it to load javascript and not give me a message. I am not sure what I am doing wrong, as I would like it to call my previous code.

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country == "CA") {
alert("Hello World");
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kWhud/

Comment: _"doesn't seem to work"_ is a broad statement, what part isnt working? are you getting errors?

Comment: I am a noob to JS. I really should have said it doesn't work.

Comment: you still havent said exactly what isnt working.

Comment: Changed to real statement. I tried to use an alert, and changed the != to a ==, but didn't get the alert when using a US IP. I also viewed the network tab within firebug, but it never 'seemed' to load the service.

Comment: It isn't loading my javascript code. It doesn't even load an alert message.

Comment: i dont see you calling `iLoader.init()` at all

Comment: Good catch, I just tried to run the code using iLoader.init() after the script and didn't get it to load still. http://screencast.com/t/1sJ3J4WKU6 . However, I finally got it to work using an alert message and using =="CA". So I am making headway.

Comment: Don't know why the negative ratings, but thanks to your help, and from below it is working now. However, when running the file on my local machine it doesnt. I uploaded it to my webserver and I am good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code. Ir works: there are right ISO-code in var country. And your if-statement is also right.

As far as I understand, you just want smth like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dehisok/kWhud/1/

```
iLoader.init();
```

You miss this code, as for me. You have just define some object with init method, but it needs to be runned to load needed javascript-file.

Yo can remove

```
 console.log(scrNode);
```

and your code will work in needed way.

Comment: You are right, it does work. When I uploaded this to my server, I was good. However, trying it on my local machine I got this result http://screencast.com/t/1sJ3J4WKU6 . It wasn't acting as it should, it wasn't providing me with the javascript applet despite me being NOT canada and using a US address. THanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a redirection service that doesn't require any javascript. One of them is redirectbycountry.com

Comment: Great to hear about this service, but it wouldn't work for my needs.